# XSL - intersect two collections and return the common value found

Tags: xslt

I need to write an XSL transformation so that I can be able to tell if one of the options from `configuration/selectedOptions` node is among the ones from the `availableOptions` node and return that value.

For the XML structure bellow I should return `A` because it's in both collections. There will always be only one value returned.

The simplified XML structure is the following:

```
<availableOptions>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</availableOptions>

<configuration>
    <selectedOptions>A,M,P,T,S</selectedOptions>
</configuration>
```

As for the XSL, all that I have written so far is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="hasSelectedOption">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(//configurations/selectedOptions, ',')">
    <xsl:if test=".= 'A'">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>            
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

It works fine so far, it loops through the `configuration/selectedOptions` and returns `A` if it finds it in the collection, but I don't know how to replace that hardcoded `A` with all the values from `availableOptions/option`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a variable to hold the tokenized options like so...

```
 <xsl:variable name="selectedOptions" select="tokenize(//configuration/selectedOptions, ',')" />
```

You can then get the option that is available like so....

```
<xsl:variable name="hasSelectedOption" select="//availableOptions/option[. = $selectedOptions]" />
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks, Tim.